# Does Inet 4.2 support of partially overlapped channel?

Tags: omnet++

Does Inet 4.2 support POC (Partially Overlapped Channel)?
I run a simulation but it occurred a partially overlapped channel error in simulating process. The error description says you must set ignorePartialInterference parameter to false. But I think the accuracy of results would be lower.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INET 4.2 supports partially overlapping Wifi channels, but you have to use a dimensional analog model.
These should be helpful:

https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/crosstalk/doc/index.html
https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/coexistence/doc/index.html